# Ignore "still reachable" when setting return value

Tags: c++, valgrind

In a CI system I run a bunch tests with valgrind, where I expect return value `0` if no errors are found by valgrind and `1` otherwise. The tests itself run successfully and return `0`.

This is what `error-exitcode` seems to be for:

```
--error-exitcode=<number> exit code to return if errors found [0=disable]
```

Now I have a program that produces `still reachable` from a 3rd party library. Not ideal, but okay. I try to define that `still reachable` is not an error by calling:

```
valgrind --errors-for-leak-kinds=definite,indirect,possible --error-exitcode=1 ./tests
```

which prints

```
==9198== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9198==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9198==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9198==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9198==    still reachable: 392 bytes in 4 blocks
==9198==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

but still returns `1`.

Is there a way to ignore `still reachable` in the return value?

Comment: i don't think its supposed to report 1 for 'still reachable', because those are not classified as errors by Valgrind. What does your Error Summary say?

Comment: If valgrind says there is no error - it wouldn't reassign process's return code. In that case `1` is what your target process have returned. If you don't use `--error-exitcode`, valgrind will never reassign exit code.

Comment: I can't replicate this using valgrind 3.9.0.  It always returns 0 even when there are "still reachable" blocks.  Can you provide a complete working example with the C++ program required?

Comment: @keltar Good point, but the tests run sucessfully and return `0` without valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Use

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 ./tests
```

---

Okay I think I found the answer when building the SSCCE

**SSCCE**

Let `memLeakTest.cpp` be

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void makeDefinitelyLostPointer()
{
    int* definitelyLostPointer = new int(5555);
    (*definitelyLostPointer) += 1;
}

void makeStillReachablePointer()
{
    int* stillReachablePointer = new int(3333);
    std::exit(0);
    (*stillReachablePointer) += 1;
}

int main()
{
    //makeDefinitelyLostPointer();
    makeStillReachablePointer();
    return 0;
}
```

1. Run `g++ memLeakTest.cpp -o memLeakTest`
2. Run `./memLeakTest; echo $?`, which shows the return value `0`
3. Run `valgrind ./memLeakTest; echo $?`, returns `0`
4. Run `valgrind --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 ./memLeakTest`, returns `0` if `makeDefinitelyLostPointer()` is disabled and `1` if `makeDefinitelyLostPointer()` is enabled. In both cases there are still reachables.